# ssh issue coreOS on AWS (EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, coreos, kubernetes

I am following instructions on:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/coreos_multinode_cluster.md

I am trying to launch a Master with master.yaml file as a UserData. I am able to successfully launch the instance in EC2 but i cant seem to ssh to it via aws ssh key..

`backend-service viralcarpenter$ ssh -i ~/Downloads/viral-kubernetes-acad-key.pem core@54.153.63.240
core@54.153.63.240's password:`

Is there something that i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Key Pair configured in your EC2 region and specify it when creating the instance in order to be able to SSH into it.

```
--key-name <keypair>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues and have a key pair specified. When I attempt to SSH into the server it asks for a password (even though the key pair isn't password protected).